# Presentation software, or something similar, that lets you edit a presentation while in presentation mode?

Tags: presentation

I'm looking for a way to present to a live audience and incorporate their input into my presentation. As most presenting software currently works, the presentation is static. It can't be manipulated while in presenter mode. This makes for an ugly presentation if you have to keep taking down, editing, and then re-presenting the slide deck. Is there any software, presentation or otherwise that solves this problem?

I have found this [ProPresenter](http://www.renewedvision.com/) but with no full demo I'm unwilling to spend $399 on it.

Comment: Nice idea. I'll think about it

Comment: Apple presented a feature like this at their September 2016 event.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Do you have a link to the presentation?

Comment: @PhilAndrews [September Event 2016 (6:12)](https://youtu.be/NS0txu_Kzl8?t=981)

Comment: "ive audience and incorporate their input into my presentation" do you mean online multiple screen?

Answer (score 0):

While not originally presentation software, the [iMapping Tool](http://www.imapping.info/what-is-imapping/) is also used for presentations and lets you edit and re-structure the contents while presenting.

It needs to be said though, that iMapping is not comparable to a slideshow manager like PowerPoint, it is rather like prezi, where you create a large overview canvas and zoom into details. The core differences to prezi are that a) it is not primarily a presentation toll but designed to be a structured knowledge management tool that also happens to be cool for presenting. b) it is not webbased but offline and stand-alone.

It also needs to be said, that yes, I do have stakes in it: I developped iMapping.
And while there is an eternally free version availlable, there also is a commercial one.

Why don't you give it a try and post your verdict here?

Answer (score 0):

[Prezi](http://prezi.com)'s editor mode is almost identical to the presenting mode. There's a side and topbar, but doesn't distract as much as PowerPoint's ribbon bar.
In the editor mode you can make quick changes.

Otherwise take a look at [Mentimeter](https://www.mentimeter.com/) which is one of the best software I know to engage with your audience.